# Create end_time variable on row A from start_time variable on row B

Tags: r

I would like to create an end_time variable for each participant based on their start_times and time_end_of_experiment (minus say 10 ms), but quite unsure how to do this.

Here's a minimal working example

```
df <- data.frame("subject_nr" = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2"),
                 "start_time" = c(50, 52, 55, 53, 54.5),
                 "time_end_of_experiment" = c(60, 60, 60, 55.5, 55.5))


  subject_nr start_time time_end_of_experiment
1          1       50.0                   60.0
2          1       52.0                   60.0
3          1       55.0                   60.0
4          2       53.0                   55.5
5          2       54.5                   55.5
```

Here's what the final product should look like

```
  subject_nr start_time end_time time_end_of_experiment  
1          1       50.0     51.9                     60
2          1       52.0     54.9                     60
3          1       55.0     59.9                     60
4          2       53.0     54.4                   55.5
5          2       54.5     55.4                   55.5
```

Comment: Hi, for me it is not really clear, what do you exactly want. Do you want the difference between the rows for each subject? Are all of the differences between the rows for each subject equal and should sum up to `time_end_of_experiment`? Can you describe your question and aim in more detail?

Comment: Thanks fbeese, sorry for the unclarity. TarJae's answer below solves it exactly. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we could do it:
First use `lead` to substract 0.1 from `lead(start_time)`
then for the last value in the groups use an ifelse statement to substract 0.1 from time_end_of_experiment:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(subject_nr) %>% 
  mutate(end_time = lead(start_time, default = last(start_time))-.1, .before=3) %>% 
  mutate(end_time = ifelse(start_time == last(start_time), time_end_of_experiment-.1, end_time))
```

```
  subject_nr start_time end_time time_end_of_experiment
  <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 1                50       51.9                   60  
2 1                52       54.9                   60  
3 1                55       59.9                   60  
4 2                53       54.4                   55.5
5 2                54.5     55.4                   55.5
```